# Missing Reference Exception Unity C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue in my Unity game with my enemy lists where if a group is empty it will still run through the for loop causing a missing reference exception citing the 'enemyGroupList[i][j].enabled = true;' line in the error and not spawning a new group. I think it's not removing the empty list but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't.

I wasn't having this issue before when I had the for loop as

```
for(int j = enemyGroupList.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
```

This was throwing an argument out of range exception and wasn't what I needed there but it would update the groups properly and spawn a new one when needed.

```
void Update () {
    if(enemyGroupList.Count < groupNumber)
    {
        enemyGroupList.Add(createGroup());
    }

    // for each list in the group list
    for(int i = enemyGroupList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // for each opject in a given list
        for (int j = enemyGroupList[i].Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {

            // pause and unpause enemies when the player pauses the game or is talking
            if (player.CurrState == PlayerScript.State.Paused || player.CurrState == PlayerScript.State.Talking)
            {
                enemyGroupList[i][j].enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                enemyGroupList[i][j].enabled = true;
            }

            // remove dead enemies
            if (enemyGroupList[i][j].Dead)
            {
                enemyGroupList[i].RemoveAt(j);
                // break avoids out of range exceptions
            }
        }
        if (enemyGroupList[i].Count == 0 || player.CurrState == PlayerScript.State.Win)
        {
            enemyGroupList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Two questions. Where do you instantiate `enemyGroupList`? Is `enemyGroupList` a static variable inside this class (which seems to be some class inheriting a `MonoBehaviour`)?

Comment: This is just the update method. I'm instantiating it as a global list outside of the update method. Yes, this class is inheriting from MonoBehavior

Comment: But is it static? Do you have this `MonoBehavior` attached to more than one `GameObject`? This would be one possibility, because your `reverse loops` seem fine.

Comment: It is not static and the behavior is only attached to one object.

Comment: I was able to fix it by giving the enemy objects a destroy function and having the enemy manager call the function when it removes the enemy from the list.